# Getting last 2 digits after multiplication

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of integer numbers, my task is to get the last 2 digits after multiplying all these numbers.

I have come up with the below code:

```
static void process(int array[]) {
    if (array.length <= 0) {
        System.out.println("-1");
        return;
    }
    int answer = array[0] % 100;

    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        answer = (answer * array[i] % 100) % 100;
    }

    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

I felt this is a better approach, but when I used this during one my exams it passed only 2 out of 4 test cases. The test cases failed due to performance issues. The failed test cases were hidden, so not able to see them.

I even tried the alternate approach like initializing a long variable to 1 then using a for loop and multiplying the long variable with array element. Finally getting the last two digits from long variable, even that failed with 2 test cases.

Is there any better approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that it is due to performance issues? If yes, then I think it is kind of a stupid question, because O(n) is the best you can get.

My guess is that it was because your answer wasn't correct. E.g. if your answer is "1", then it could actually be "01". So a correct implementation would take that into account.

```
boolean atLeast10 = false;
int answer = 1;
int i = 0;
for (; i < array.length && !atLeast10; i++) {
    if (array[i] == 0) {
        System.out.println(0);
        return;
    }
    answer = answer * array[i];
    if (answer >= 10)
        atLeast10 = true;
}
answer = answer % 100;
for (; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == 0) {
        System.out.println(0);
        return;
    }
    answer = (answer * array[i] % 100) % 100;
}
if (!atLeast10 || answer >= 10)
    System.out.println(answer);
else
    System.out.println("0" + answer);
```

Btw. shortcut is only possible if an element is 0, this is again because even if the number ends in "00" there could follow a 0 much later in the array and then the answer is "0" and not "00", although I like the idea.

Answer (score 3):

There are some potential shortcuts. Multiplying by a number ending in 0 or two numbers ending in 2 and 5 respectively would guarantee the last digit is a 0.  Doing that twice makes your last two digits 00 and you can print the result early.  You could check whether your answer is 00 and break out of the loop if that happens.

This would slow down your algorithm against data that is tailored against this check. However, a large (>1000) randomized set of numbers would be be almost guaranteed to end in 00 early and be faster than your initial approach.

Sample code:

```
static void process(int array[]) {
  if (array.length <= 0) {
      System.out.println("-1");
      return;
  }
  int answer = array[0] % 100;

  for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(answer == 0) {
       break;
    }
    answer = (answer * array[i] % 100) % 100;
  }

  System.out.println(answer);
}
```